# 2 Tokens generated for one login

Tags: authentication, access-token, strongloop

I've created my Own user Class by extending the User built-in class.
But when I login loopback writes 2 tokens per login to the database.
Is this a bug ? do I need a workaround ?

Comment: Can you provide some code and explain further?

Comment: That might be a bit difficult, it's on another system one without no gui.
I also noticed that the tokens don't get removed on logout. realy wierd behaviour. I cant imagine that i need to recreate the built-in has_many->AccessToken relation. But i did set a ttl on the tokens going to remove that. And see what happens.

Comment: okay, ttl has nothing to do with it, i also get a bad gateway error on logout.
doen't get any better :s

Comment: removed an afterRemote("logout",...
The bad gateway is gone, but now I get a "could not find accessToken error" I suspect that mongo is the problem, i have a readWrite role assigend to the loopback account in mongo. Does anyone know if that's okay or do I need dbOwner ?

Comment: Okay, dbOwner seems to be needed, for loopback, the fact that the database didn't had it, generated the not found and bad gateway ( beforeRemote method failed )

But i still get 2 tokens on logout only one gets deleted

Comment: To me it feels like User.prototype.createAccessToken() is called 2 times, one time from the custom extending class and one from the User base-class.

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

It looks like you always need to call next() in beforeRemote methods even if it's in code that's only reached when an error happens, and even when that everything runs smooth.